# spin multiple instances of different images using terraform on openstack

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-openstack

I've been trying to spin up multiple instances of different images using terraform but haven't had luck so far. I could spin multiple instances of a single image with `count`. While spinning up different images with `for_each`, I couldn't get the right configuration.

I've the below variable .tf configuration file.

```
variable "images" {
  type = map
  default = {
    "rhel-8-factory-os-ready" = {
       "az_zone" = "eu-fra-1ah"
       "ins_count" = 2
     }
    "rhel-7-factory-os-ready" = {
       "az_zone" = "eu-fra-1ai"
       "ins_count" = 2
    }
  }
}

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instance" {
   for_each = var.images
   flavor_id = var.flavor
   image_name = each.key
   name = "${var.image_name}-${lower(random_id.random-instance.hex)}"
   availability_zone = each.value.az_zone
   security_groups = var.security_group
   key_pair = "fop-mgt-key"
   network {
     name = var.network_name
   }
}

resource "random_id" "random-instance" {
  byte_length = 4
}

resource "random_id" "random-number" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "openstack_networking_floatingip_v2" "fip" {
  count = length(var.images)
  pool = var.floatingip_pool
}

resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "fip" {

  depends_on = [openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance]

  count = length(var.images)
  floating_ip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.fip[count.index].address
  instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance.*.id[count.index]
  fixed_ip    = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance.*.network.0.fixed_ip_v4[count.index]
}

terraform {
  backend "artifactory" {}
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "foo" {
  backend = "artifactory"
  config = {
    repo = "${var.repo}"
    subpath = "${var.subpath}"
  }
}
```

I see the below error message ::

> Error: Unsupported attribute
>
> on tf-backend-fra/main.tf line 49, in resource
>   "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "fip":   49:   instance_id
>   = openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance.*.id[count.index]
>
> This object does not have an attribute named "id".

I'm not sure how to get it done with `for_each`. Terraform version is 0.12.17.
Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 1):

Somehow managed to solve with `lookup` and `element` like below.

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instance" {
   for_each = var.images
   flavor_id = each.value.flavor
   image_id = lookup(data.openstack_images_image_v2.os-image, each.key).id
   name = "${var.image_name}-${lower(random_id.random-instance.hex)}"
   availability_zone = each.value.az_zone
   security_groups = var.security_group
   key_pair = "fop-mgt-key"
   network {
     name = var.network_name
   }
}

resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "fip" {
  for_each = var.images
  floating_ip = element(openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.fip, index(tolist(keys(var.images)), each.key)).address
  instance_id = lookup(openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance, each.key).id
  fixed_ip    = lookup(openstack_compute_instance_v2.instance, each.key).network.0.fixed_ip_v4
}
```